# How do i delete multiple files from a MS DOS batch file using a wildcard when the path includes spaces?

Tags: windows, batch-file, filepath

Say I have a directory with the following files in it:

Test.bat
Test_a.txt
Test_b.txt
Test_v1.zip
Test_v2.zip
Test_v3.zip

I want to delete all `Test_v*.zip` quietly (no error messages logged to screen). I can achieve this with the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET OLD_ZIPS=^
C:\Tmp\Test_v*.txt;^
C:\Tmp\Test_a.txt

ECHO Deleting the following files: %OLD_ZIPS%

FOR %%Y IN (%OLD_ZIPS%) DO (
IF EXIST %%Y (
ECHO  Deleting %%Y
DEL /Q %%Y)
)

PAUSE
```

This works fine:

```
Deleting the following files: C:\Tmp\Test_v*.txt;C:\Tmp\Test_a.txt
Deleting "C:\Tmp\Test_v1.txt"
Deleting "C:\Tmp\Test_v2.txt"
Deleting "C:\Tmp\Test_a.txt"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

*Unless* of course the file paths contain spaces. So in the example above, if I change `C:\Tmp\Test_v*.txt` to `C:\Tmp with spaces\Test_v*.txt` I get:

```
Deleting the following files: C:\Tmp test\Test_v*.txt;C:\Tmp test\Test_a.txt
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I stop it baulking at the spaces?

**Edit** - I've tried spaces as per Alex K's answer (plus a little more debug) and it looks like perhaps the for loop isn't splitting things up as I expect:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET OLD_ZIPS=^
C:\Tmp test\Test_v*.txt;^
C:\Tmp test\Test_a.txt

ECHO Deleting the following files: %OLD_ZIPS%

FOR %%Y IN (%OLD_ZIPS%) DO (
ECHO  Checking existance of "%%Y"
IF EXIST "%%Y" (
ECHO  Deleting "%%Y"
DEL /Q "%%Y")
)

PAUSE
```

..gives me:

```
Deleting the following files: C:\Tmp test\Test_v*.txt;C:\Tmp test\Test_a.txt
 Checking existance of "C:\Tmp"
 Checking existance of "C:\Tmp"
 Checking existance of "test\Test_a.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs to loop over each line individually, so you need to quote the variable in the FOR loop, tokenize it on the semicolons, rinse and repeat.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET OLD_ZIPS=^
C:\tmp with spaces\Test_v*.txt;^
C:\tmp\Test_a.txt

ECHO Deleting the following files: %OLD_ZIPS%

:deleteFiles
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in ("%OLD_ZIPS%") do (
    ECHO  Checking existance of "%%A"
    IF EXIST "%%A" (
        ECHO  Deleting "%%A"
        DEL /Q "%%A"
    )
    set OLD_ZIPS=%%B
)
if not "%OLD_ZIPS%" == "" goto :deleteFiles

PAUSE
```

Comment: Nice work Kevin; that worked a treat! I tried the tokens / delims bit but I was using `tokens=*` and didn't get the right answer..

Answer (score 2):

seems you are trying to over complicate things.

```
for %a in ("C:\Tmp with spaces\Test_v*.txt" "C:\Tmp\Test_a.txt") do del /q "%a"
```

does what you want, and can be typed from the command line. change %a to %%a if you want to do it in a batch file

Answer (score -1):

Weirdly, this seems to work. I have editted my version to look like yours so please try and amend any syntax errors ;-)

```
@ECHO OFF
SET OLD_ZIPS="C:\Tmp with spaces\Test_v*.txt";^
"C:\Tmp with spaces\Test_a.txt";

ECHO Deleting the following files: %OLD_ZIPS%

FOR %%Y IN (%OLD_ZIPS%) DO (
IF EXIST %%Y (
ECHO  Deleting %%Y
DEL /Q %%Y)
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: It does work. I mistakingly pasted your paths without spaces back in. The paths on my machine when I tested had spaces. It's the quotes on the paths that make the difference with spaces. It doesn't seem to work with ^ directly after the ZIPS= though. I've updated the paths now.

Comment: I get: `Deleting the following files: "C:\Tmp test\Test_v*.txt";"C:\Tmp test\Test_a.txt";
 Deleting C:\Tmp test\Test_v1.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
 Deleting C:\Tmp test\Test_v2.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
 Deleting "C:\Tmp test\Test_a.txt"` and neither `Test_v1.txt` nor `Test_v2.txt` get deleted. I'm running on windows 7 if that makes a difference?